# Polymer function binding in html with object as second argument

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

I'm running into an issue with Polymer 1.x with a custom localization element I'm creating. When binding to a function in HTML it appears I cannot pass an argument in as an object. The my-element textContent gets the entire function as a string, rather than the returned value from the function. See the sample code below for an example or this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4n2da6sr/1/.

HTML:

```
<dom-module id="x-example">
    <template>
      <h1>[[getText('Hello world', {context: 'general'})]]</h1>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<x-example></x-example>
```

JavaScript:

```
let strings = {
    general: {
      'Hello world': {
      message: 'Hola Mundo'
    }
};

Polymer({
    is: 'x-example',
    getText: function(key, options = {context: 'general'}) {
        let context = options.context;
        let localMessage = key;

        if (strings && strings[context][key]) {
            let message = strings[context][key].message;
            localMessage = message || key;
        }

      return localMessage;
    }
});
```

This getText function returns just the localized message or key, and uses the second parameter (an object) as additional options for filtering the message. So in the example above I'd expect to get an output of:

```
"Hola Mundo"
```

But instead I get the whole function evaluated as a string:

```
"getText('Hello world', {context: 'general'})"
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've not used polymer but I've read that using an ID for your element and relying on it for linkage will go wrong in the shadow dom where a different id will be used

Comment: @AMacdonald thanks, but this is just example code, so that's just for making it easier to read here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A computed binding is similar to a computed property: it includes a
>   computing function and zero or more arguments. **Arguments can be
>   dependent properties or string or number literals.**

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed

The problem with your invocation of `getText()` is that you're passing an object literal, when it only accepts strings, numbers, and properties.

If you re-structure your element so that `options` and `strings` are properties you can get it working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841958">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
  <script href="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
</head>

<body>

  <dom-module id="x-example">
    <template>
      <h1>[[getText('Hello world', options, strings)]]</h1>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-example',
        properties: {
          options: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true,
            value: function() { 
              return {'context': 'general'}; 
            }
          },
          strings: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true,
            value: function() { 
              return {
                'general': {
                  'Hello world': {
                    'message': 'Hola Mundo'
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        getText: function(key, options, strings) {
          let context = options.context;
          let localMessage = key;

          if (strings[context][key]) {
            let message = strings[context][key].message;

            localMessage = message || key;
          }

          return localMessage;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <x-example></x-example>
</body>

</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/tagohu/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 1):

Make your object an property and then use it

```js
let strings = {
    general: {
      'Hello world': {
        message: 'Hola Mundo'
      }
    }
};

Polymer({
  is: 'x-example',
  properties:{
   options:{
    type:Object,
    value:{context:'general'}
    }
  },
  getText: function(key,options = {context: 'general'}) {
    let context = options.context;
    let localMessage = key;

    if (strings && strings[context][key]) {
      let message = strings[context][key].message;

      localMessage = message || key;
    }

    return localMessage;
  }
});
```

```css
     body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
      <h1>
          [[getText('Hello world',options)]]
      </h1>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<x-example></x-example>
```